# Local Command Line Debugging with XDebug and PHPStorm, MAMP Pro, OS X

Tags: php, debugging, mamp, xdebug

Previously I had MAMP v2.x working great with XDebug. It was configured so I could toggle it on and off for each browser connection using the following bookmarked JavaScript:

```
javascript:(/**%20@version%200.5.2%20*/function()%20{document.cookie='XDEBUG_SESSION='+'PHPSTORM'+';path=/;';})()

javascript:(/**%20@version%200.5.2%20*/function()%20{document.cookie='XDEBUG_SESSION='+''+';expires=Mon,%2005%20Jul%202000%2000:00:00%20GMT;path=/;';})()
```

I could also debug scripts executed on the command line with bash turning debugging on and off with:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
unset XDEBUG_CONFIG
```

I've upgraded to MAMP Pro 3.x and have debugging working from a browser and can turn it on and off with the JS bookmarks. However, I've been unable to get debugging to work from terminal. The default install for MAMP is for XDebug to autostart. I do not want that since it prevents access to other sites on the server during debugging so I've modified the config. Here's what I have:

```
[xdebug]
 MAMP_Xdebug_MAMP
 xdebug.remote_enable=on
 xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
 xdebug.remote_host=localhost
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
 xdebug.remote_mode=req
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

So that my script uses the correct php binary I've sym linked /usr/bin/php to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.30/bin/php

I've also tried turning xdebug.remote_autostart back on to see if I could get debugging from terminal working. No go.

The web has lots of info on how to do remote command line debugging but I've found nothing that helps on local command line debugging.

I'm looking for ideas on how I can get local command line debugging working with MAMP Pro 3.x.

SOLUTION UPDATE: I ran a script with phpinfo() from cli and saw that for some reason when calling php from the command line, it loads a different php.ini. I added the following to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.30/conf/php.ini and it now works!

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

Thanks to @Niloct for sparking the idea that led me to the solution though I am ashamed I did not think of it at first. :/

Comment: Is the listen button on phpstorm enabled ?

Comment: Yes the listen button is enabled. I also tested debugging from the browser to confirm it was listening then immediately tried cli.

Comment: Wow. 1 1/2 years later I upgrade computers and have the same problem. Googling I find my own answer and it is the solution I needed. Wish I could upvote it. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP setup directory, be sure the configuration `xdebug.ini` is in `conf.d` directory so cli and webserver get xdebug activated:

```
MacBook:5.5 teixeira$ pwd
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5

MacBook:5.5 teixeira$ ls
conf.d               php-fpm.conf         php.ini
pear.conf            php-fpm.conf.default

MacBook:5.5 teixeira$ ack -i xdebug
conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
1:[xdebug]
2:zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55-xdebug/2.2.4/xdebug.so"
3:xdebug.remote_enable = 1
4:xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
5:xdebug.remote_port = 9005
6:xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
7:xdebug.profiler_enable=0
8:xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
9:xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
10:xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

then issue `php -i | grep xdebug` to check if it's loaded in CLI.

ALSO, triple check the port, notice that I'm using `9005` because of conflict I had with `php-fpm`.

Comment: Not the actual solution but accepting it as answer since all I asked for was ideas and yours did the trick. :)

Comment: Yeah breaking the innertia is important :) glad to see that.